# How can i call DLL function in website runnng on .NET 2

Tags: c#

I'm working on this website, trying to call a function from a C# DLL through `default.asmx.cs`

It works fine with .NET version 3.5, but our production site is .NET 2.0

I'm using a simple ajax request to call the method in `default.asmx` and from there to the DLL. I found that I can not use [WebMethod] in NET2, what could be the other way to work around this?

```
//this is the Handler
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string removeAutoRecharge(string custServiceid)
    {
        Class1 jp = new Class1();
        return jp.removeCustomerAutoRecharge(custServiceid);
    }
}
```

//Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url:"default.asnx/removeAutoRecharge",
    data: "{custId:123}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    complete:function (xhr, status)
    {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert(xhr.status);
    },
        success: function(result) 
    {
        $('#AutoMSG').html(result.d);
    },
    error: function(xmlHttpRequest, status, err) 
    {
        $('#AutoMSG').html("error!")
    }
});
```

Comment: If the dll is built for .net 3.5, you won't be able to use it within a .net 2 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the source code for this dll? [WebMethod] works in .net 2. Perhaps you can modify the project that created that binary, and make it a .net 2 project.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

This I ran using .net 2 project:

[image]

Comment: thank you...yes i have code for the DLL, and it's already on version 2.

Comment: [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string removeSavedCC(string profileid)
    {
        Class1 jp = new Class1();
        return jp.removeCustomerCC(profileid);
    }                                                                    that is how i am trying to call DLL function from default.asnx.cs..it works well with our test site and localhost...on live website it gives me status code 200 and text ok..responseText comes blank.

Comment: Oh but i missing to say that this is a Class library... can we still use [WebMethod] tag??

Comment: There's no reason you can't use it. You need to include the references and namespaces though: using System.Web; using System.Web.Services; Or you could fully qualify the attribute: [System.Web.Services.WebMethod].

Comment: I am using [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]  it returns with status 200..i tried including "complete" instead of "success" but xhr.responseText is a blank HTML form with _viewState hidden field.. i have wasted almost  week on this..

Comment: I added it above...do you want me to add DLL function??

Comment: Thank you for your help.. Problem was i can't use [webMethod] tag when function belongs to .net Class Library..it can be used with Web Service though.